# set selected value for the kendo-combobox when data bound with async pipe

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have a sample code like this

```html
    <kendo-combobox [allowCustom]="false" 
                    [suggest]="true" 
                    [data]="dropDownButtonItemsObs | async" 
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedComboBoxItem" 
                    [textField] = "'text'" [valueField] = "'value'">

    </kendo-combobox>
```

The `dropDownButtonItemsObs` is a Observable, data retrieved from the web api. 
With my example above - using async pipe, can you guide an example how to programmatic set the selected item for the combo box?

Answer (score 0):

figured out how to have it set up, however I feel my code is not the fully exactly the option using async pipe as it is in the document http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/combobox/data-binding/#toc-async-pipe

```html
  this.dropDownButtonItemsObs = this.dashboardService.getDropdownItems();
  this.dropDownButtonItemsObs.subscribe(dropdownItems => {
   this.dashboardService.getDropdownSelectedValue().subscribe(data => {
    this.selectedComboBoxItem = dropdownItems.find(item => { return item.value === 2 });
   });
  });
```